# Is there a way to fix the HTML validation error? While keeping using the SVG as the source code of the `<img>` tag?

Tags: html, image, svg

Is there a way to fix the HTML validation error? While keeping using the SVG as the source code of the `<img>` tag?

> ```
> Error: Bad value data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg 
> xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='10px' width='20px'></svg> 
> for attribute src on element`
> ```

My source code:

```
<img alt="homepage" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg 
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='10px' width='20px'></svg>"
/>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use this inside an image element? Is it a placeholder for another image that should be loaded later? If it is, maybe you want to use native lazy loading and/or a lazy loading library. Otherwise, you could try to use an svg element instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use an SVG as a data URI within an `<img>` element, the SVG code needs to be escaped:

```
<img alt="homepage" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='10px' width='20px'%3E%3C/svg%3E">
```

There are several free tools for doing this, such as [URL-encoder for SVG](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-interactive svg, use  with script fallbacks to png version (for older IE and android < 3). One clean and simple way to do that:

```
<img src="your.svg" onerror="this.src='your.png'">
```

your.svg being the path to your svg.

This will behave much like a GIF image, and if your browser supports declarative animations (SMIL) then those will play.

If you want an interactive svg, use either `<iframe>` or `<object>`.

If you need to provide older browsers the ability to use an svg plugin, then use `<embed>`.

For svg in css background-image and similar properties, modernizr is one choice for switching to fallback images, another is depending on multiple backgrounds to do it automatically:

```
div {
    background-image: url(fallback.png);
    background-image: url(your.svg), none;
}
```

An additional good read is [this blogpost](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/) on svg fallbacks.

Comment: The person asking the question has the SVG inline rather than as a separate file

Comment: I will edit the answer to include this way of working with svg but the best practices recommend to use separate file when working with svg unless you're trying to animate them. As he entered a wrong src, I thought he was misunderstanding how to import it

Answer (score -1):

For inline SVG; `<svg>` tags can be inserted as `<svg>` elements directly into the HTML and not part of the `<img>` tag. As it is inline SVG the `<img>` tag is pretty redundant as all the required parameters can be held inside the `<SVG>`.

[Read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction)

Example:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>SVG Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <svg
      viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
      style="width:35%; height:35%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:-1;">
      <linearGradient id="gradient">
        <stop class="begin" offset="0%"/>
        <stop class="end" offset="100%"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" style="fill:#cc9966;" />
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" style="fill:#f9f333;" />
    </svg>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The question specifically asks for answers "keeping the SVG as the source of the `<img>` tag"